# pgAdmin 4 v3.0 and v3.1 doesn't load (crashes) on Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I tried to google issue, but I couldn't really find any help or solution that would work. It is trying to load - loading box appear, but app doesn't appear after that.

There is no log in "%APPDATA%\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.log" file or any error. There is no process after it crashes. Version v2 works properly.

I'll provide any info, you need. I am kinda out of ideas how to log / fix this.

Comment: Have you installed any previous version of pgAdmin4 version?

Comment: Yes, but never had a conflict between them. Only pgAdmin 4 v3 (or any subversion of it) doesnt work.

Comment: try deleting pgadmin4.db file from "%APPDATA%\pgAdmin\ and start pgAdmin4 again.

Comment: Just tried, still doesn't start.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it as Administrator?

If not I would suggest try it once, I don't know the exact reason but sometimes it fails to load on Windows.

I faced the same issue, Here are the steps I followed,

1) Right click on pgAdmin4 icon

2) Select 'Run as administrator' option

[image]

3) Click **Yes** on confirmation dialog and check if pgAdmin4 starts properly.

If the above steps do not solve your problem then try reaching the developers via the mailing list.
https://www.pgadmin.org/support/list/

Comment: It didn't help. Tried that long time ago. I just use older version, version which are not working for me is when pgAdmin started to using server and browsing via browser.